# Call async request to load info

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my wordpress theme, I am using api to load movie info. So, I am trying to call jquery function which will execute ajax request and load the result in a predefined DIV.

But at the time I am calling that function in my content.php page, the document.ready is not yet fulfilled. So, either I need to define the jquery function outside document.ready() (which I think is not a good idea), or I need to call that function on bodyOnload. In the latter case, I am not sure how I can include the urls which are parsed using the get_the_content() function of wordpress from page content.

Can anybody please advise.

PHP (content.php):

```
$pattern = '/REGEX/i';
$replacement = '$1';
$subject = get_the_content();
$urls = preg_split($pattern, $subject); // Let say I have all the links in this variable
echo '<script>loadMovies('.json_encode($urls).');</script>'; // loadMovies() is not available at this point
```

Now loadMovies() is defined inside custom.js like below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    function loadMovies(urls){
        console.log(urls);
        // HERE I HAVE MY AJAX CALLS WHICH IS NOT AN ISSUE
        // THE MAIN ISSUE IS THE FUNCTION IS NOT AVAILABLE AT THE POINT I CALL IT
    }
});
```

And custom.js is added using below in functions.php

```
function test_call_js(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-js',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    ); 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_call_js');
```

Comment: Why can't you just run the function at the end of the page (i.e. after the script is loaded)?

Comment: The thing is, this page uses a special template, let say card-view.php. And inside this template file, I call content.php (using get_template_part('content');) which defines the body section. So, if I call loadMovies at the end of card-view.php, for some reason the variable $urls is not available. (unlike in PHP, if I include content.php inside card-view.php, I do get access to all variables of the former).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like minus 4 stated, its a timing issue. You are calling a function which is only created on dom ready. The solution is to call the ajax function on dom ready and just output the variable you need for this function earlier in the script (where you were calling the ajax function)

i.e. content.php

```
    $urls = preg_split($pattern, $subject); // Let say I have all the links in this variable
    echo '<script> var urls='.json_encode($urls).';</script>';
```

Note all you are doing is defining urls here, this is bad mark up but it needs to be here as you are using  `the_content()` which needs to be run inside the wp loop.

in your js file

```
    function loadMovies(urls){
        console.log(urls);
        // define our function.
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        loadMovies(urls){
            console.log(urls);
            // call our predefined function
        }
    });
```

you can still define your function in your document.ready function but its cleaner to create functions and then call within other functions (in the case above its a anon function)

Answer (score 1):

You are having a scope issue. You are declaring the function inside another function, which means it won't be visible from the global scope when you add your script. You need to move the function that'll be called from your other script in the global scope.

AJAX call can still be placed at the ready event, so it will load the script once the DOM is ready.

Comment: So are you suggesting I put loadMovies outside doc.ready, and call another function callAjax() which I should put inside doc.ready?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can actually have everything on the function outside the ready handler and just call the function from inside the handler. However, I just find it odd that the function which is supposed to be called from the imported script AJAXs the script again so it can call the function again. It's a loop right there.

Comment: It gives error (and I believe that's logical). Because now loadMovies() is called correctly, but inside loadMovies() when you call callAjax(), it is not yet available (because dom is not ready). I believe it's not a scope issue, rather simply I am calling the functions before DOM is ready, but want the called functions to start working after DOM is ready.

Comment: Nope. content.php is my main page. The function I am calling thorough ajax is defined in function.php. Basically from content.php, I am just calling a JS function which in tern makes the ajax request. See, basically I called loadMovies() from content.php. loadMovies() function should make some Ajax request. But I can't take risk of making ajax request before dom is loaded. That is the dilemma.

Comment: You can just add another ready handler from inside the loadMovies () call.